# Alignment changed using linguex.sty and TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht, linguistics

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{linguex}%

\begin{document}

Davidsonian events, and makes explicit how the latter relate to
situations more generally. As she puts it:

\ex. \textit{Exemplification} \label{exemplification}\\
A situation $s$ exemplifies a proposition $p$ iff whenever there
is a part of $s$ in which $p$ is not true, then $s$ is a minimal
situation in which $p$ is true. (1)

So sentence (2a) is a property of situations such that the

\ex. \a. Ewan swam for 10 hours.
\b. $\lambda {\rm s}[{\rm
past}({\rm s}) \wedge \exists{\rm e}[{\rm e} \leq_{p} {\rm s}
\wedge {\rm swim}({\rm Ewan})({\rm e}) \wedge {\rm f}_{\rm
hour}({\rm e}) = 10]]$

As is well known, the ordering of English auxiliaries is rigid

\ex.
\a. $\{{\rm T}, {\rm Mod}\} \prec {\rm Perf} \prec {\rm Prog} \prec {\rm Pass} \prec {\rm V}$
\b. He could have been being interviewed.
\c. * John is having returned.\label{havingreturned}
\d. * John is being hunting.
\e. * John seems to have had already eaten.\label{havehad}

\end{document}
```

and the output generated as:

[image]

For HTML conversion, I've run the command "`htlatex test "xhtml" " -cunihft" " -cvalidate -p`" in MS-DOS prompt, HTML generated successfully, but the alignment went wrong. Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve the HTML output with linguistic alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment is caused just by the way web browser render the underlying HTML structure. It is possible to use some CSS to fix that. For example CSS Grid, which is fairly new and powerful tool:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Css{dt p,dd p{margin:0;padding:0;}
}

\Css{ dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / 2em 1fr;
}}

\Css{dt {
  grid-column: 1;
}}

\Css{dd {
  grid-column: 2;
}}

\Css{dt, dd {
  margin: 0;
}}
\Css{ dd.alist p{margin-top:0} }
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

Comment: You are a great asset of TeX4ht....Thanks a lot...